# Where can I find Boethius' commentary on the Isagoge?

Tags: ancient-philosophy, universals

I've read and heard many times over about Boethius' commentary on Porphyry's Isagoge, that it's an interesting text about the problem of the universals and that it was very popular in the Middle Ages.

I've looked it up on the internet, but found only mentions of it.

Is there a standard place to find it? In Latin or in any Indo-European language?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe [useful](https://academic.oup.com/book/12857/chapter-abstract/163138187?redirectedFrom=fulltext)

Comment: The relevant part is translated in [Selections from Medieval Philosophers, vol. 1](https://www.amazon.com/Selections-Medieval-Philosophers-Vol-Augustine/dp/B0027Q1RMU), pp.70-99:"*The selection which follows, the First Book of the second Commentaries on the Isagoge...  is commentary on not more than a page of text from Porphyry, and a good two-thirds of it is devoted to developing and enforcing in full detail a remark of his concerning the utility of the study of logic. The remaining part is devoted to a penetrating - and startlingly cautious - discussion of the problem of the universal.*"

Comment: The above translates 1.1-1.12, just 1.10-1.11, which is on the universals, is also translated in [Five Texts on the Mediaeval Problem of Universals](https://archive.org/details/five-texts-on-the-mediaeval-problem-of-universals-porphyry-boethius-abelard-duns-scotus-ockham/page/20/mode/2up), freely available on Internet Archive.

Comment: @Conifold, that's excellent, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Latin text of Boethius' longer and shorter commentaries on the Isagoge are available at [The Logic Museum](https://www.logicmuseum.com/wiki/Authors/Boethius/isagoge). You can also find an older print edition of the text in vol. 64 of Migne's Patrologia Latina, hyperlinks for online print editions of which are available [here](https://patristica.net/latina/#t064).